# Arranging letters, with 2 letters next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different arrangements can be made with the letters of the word algebra? in how many ways of these arrangements will l and r be next to each other?
How will I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen any similar problems before?

Comment: Rule of product.  (*For second part, pick whether $L$ is to the left or the right of $R$*) Pick the position that the $L$ is in.  Pick the position that the $R$ is in.  Pick the positions that the A's are in.  Pick the position that the G is in.  Pick the position that the E is in.  Pick the position that the B is in.  Apply rule of product and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119044/what-is-the-proof-of-permutations-of-similar-objects).

For the first question consider that to arrange $7$ different items you have $7!$ permutations. But you have two $a$ , so you can interchange them which means you can divide the total number by $2!$ then the result is $\frac{7!}{2!}$.

Now for the second one consider that you can put $lr$ or $rl$ in any of the possible six positions available ( remember that you have $2$ letters to place), and then you rearrange all the other letters as usual. So the result is $2 \cdot 6 \cdot \frac{5!}{2!}$.

Comment: @MultiCore, Did you solve the problem?